# What is the relation between the generating function and the extinction probability?

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions

I was assigned to prove, given that the offspring distribution $X$ for a branching process has mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2<\infty$, the following inequality: $q\leq1-\frac{\mu-1}{\sigma^2+\mu^2-\mu}$, where $q:=\mathbb{P}(\text{Branching process will go extinct})$. Using the properties of the generating function $f_X(s):=f(s)$, I know that I am able to rewrite this as
$$q=f(q)\leq1-\frac{f'(1)-1}{f''(1)}=f(1)-\frac{f'(1)-f(1)}{f''(1)}$$
This has resulted in absolutely nothing, so far. I have been wondering what the connection could possibly be that makes this problem make sense to me. I have tried to rewrite it in several different forms, to no avail. For example, perhaps the form $\frac{\mu-1}{f''(1)}\leq1-q=\mathbb{P(\text{Branching process goes on forever})}$ would offer more insight. I still didn't figure out how this could be connected to the second derivative of the generating function at $s=1$, though.
This is an assignment, so I'm not asking that anyone solve this problem for me, but I would appreciate any hint as to where I could start looking, as I have been stuck on this for a while now.
Edit: I found a proof for this inequality under the assumption that $1-q=\mathbb{P}(Z_t>0 \forall t>0)=\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t>0)$, where $Z_t$ is the population of generation $t$. However, I'm not $100$% sure that this is an enitrely "legal" equality. If anyone could confirm whether $\mathbb{P(\text{Branching process goes on forever})}=\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t>0)$, then that would solve my problem immediately.

Comment: What do you mean by $\mathbb P(\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t)\gt0$? That limit need not exist. Do you mean the probability that it exits and is greater than $0$? I would have thought that this probability would be $0$ for any non-trivial branching process.

Comment: Why does it need not exist? If $Z_t=0$ at some $t=t_0$, then $Z_{t>t_0}=0$ as well, I thought. The reason why I want to use this, is because I want to use the Paley-Zygmund inequality, and apply it for $\theta=\frac{1}{\mu^t}$, for $\mu>1$, since the inequality trivially holds for $\mu\leq1$. I can then find an upper bound, which leads to $\frac{\mu-1}{f'''(1)}\leq \lim_{t\to\infty}(2\mu-\frac{2}{\mu^{t-1}}+\frac{1}{\mu^{2t-1}})(\frac{\mu-1}{f'''(1)})$ which is obviously true.

Comment: I meant to put $f''(1)$ in the comment above, but cannot edit it now. The inequality seemed to fall out too naturally for it to be a coincidence, but perhaps I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, certainly, if $Z=0$ at some point, then the limit exists. "It need not exist" means it doesn't necessarily exist. If the process doesn't go extinct, the limit will typically not exist.

Comment: I believe I fail to conceptually grasp why the limit would not exist. I get that the limit of $Z_t$ goes to either $0$, or infinity. But I don't quite see how it follows from that that $\mathbb{P}(\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t>0)$ does not exist. How else would you define $1-q$? Either way, does that mean I can't apply the idea I had in any sense, then? Or is there some way to salvage it. The idea is basically using Payley-Zigmund with $\mathbb{E}Z_t=\mu^t$ and $\theta=1/\mu^t$, which is in the interval $(0,1)$, since I've assumed $\mu>1$.

Comment: OK, if you count $\infty$ as a possible limit, then the limit exists almost surely. But then I don't understand the question in your edit – how could $\mathbb P(Z_t\gt0\forall t\gt0)=\mathbb P(\lim_{t\to\infty}Z_t\gt0)$ fail to hold in this case?

Comment: I wasn't sure, I just wrote it down without any rigour, because I wanted to mold it into a form that I could use. Anyway, I guess that means the issue has been resolved, so I've appreciated your insight. Thanks.